# Using display table for ul and display table-cell for li's

Tags: css

I've made a navigation and am using display:table for the ul and display:table-cell for the li's, one problem I'm facing is the li's with the display:table-cell property are always the same height as the ul, which I don't want them to be.

I've tried the obvious; height:45px!important; for the li element but it is still stretching to fill the ul.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks.

```
#navigation ul {
    width:960px;
    height:100%;
    margin:auto;
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#navigation ul li {
    display:table-cell;
    height:45px!important;
    position:relative;
    line-height:45px!important;
    text-align:center;
    color:#f1f1f1;
    border:1px solid transparent;
    z-index:5000;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to use `display: table` for that?

Comment: A table is meant to be uniform in height per row. If you don't want that, don't display it as a table.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the nature, and actually a huge advantage, of display: table-cell. If you don't want the heights matched and you're just trying to vertically align the elements, try display: inline-block and vertical-align: center on the LI elements instead of using table-cell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, explains a fair bit. I'm actually using display: table and table cell to make the navigation more responsive. By using table cell with a fixed table layout the list items will stretch with borders or any other elements to equally fit the display: table ul. I was hoping there was a little workaround as I greatly dislike using percentage based widths.